# How to fix this Error : Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554 in Android Studio

Tags: android

[Error Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554 in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1b3y.png)

[Virtual phone is not showing interfaces It's blank why is that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Ram.jpg)

Comment: you can write good questions if you can read this link,https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-ask-a-question-that-gets-answered-on-stack-overflow-45f87f1a2fef

Answer (score 0):

adb is responsible for display. I found that this error occurred from the global **adb version too old**. So I update the path to adb inside the sdk specified in Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted My all the virtual diviced then I create after that that one also not worked
again I got another device
This divice I can select emulator option to software after that It work properly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojv2o.png)